# Magento- How to passing data between model and controller

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

Thanks for previous replies,

I am new to magento framework. can anyone guide me how to get the return values from model to controller. in simple i want to return the values from model folder to controller action.

Comment: what you are returning from model.give some code

Comment: Just returning "Hello world" string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('<module>/<module>')->getCollection();
```

`<module>` represents  model name

Comment: Thanks for the replies, you are mentioned two module. what is the first module and what is the second ..??

Comment: read this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Comment: i am getting "Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in" this kind of error while calling the model function.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, controller sets values on Models, then Blocks and templates reads them from the those Models. For example, we can set a string hello by using core/session model

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setHello('hello');
```

Then we can get this hello from a block or a template or anywhere else by

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHello();
```